# Python - Pandas: select first observation per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to adapt my former SAS code to Python using the `dataframe` framework.
In SAS I often use this type of code (assume the columns are sorted by group_id where group_id takes values 1 to 10 where there are multiple observations for each group_id):

```
data want;set have;
by group_id;
if first.group_id then c=1; else c=0;
run;
```

so what goes on here is that I select the first observations for each id and I create a new variable `c` that takes value `1` and `0` for the others. The dataset looks like this:

```
group_id c
1        1  
1        0
1        0
2        1
2        0
2        0
3        1
3        0
3        0
```

How can I do this in Python using `dataframe`? Assume that I start with the `group_id` vector only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using 0.13+ you can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items) groupby method:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
   group_id
0         1
1         1
2         1
3         2
4         2
5         2
6         3
7         3
8         3

In [12]: df.groupby('group_id').cumcount() == 0
Out[12]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool
```

You can force the dtype to be int rather than bool:

```
In [13]: df['c'] = (df.groupby('group_id').cumcount() == 0).astype(int)
```

Comment: OK thanks that should work... I have to install 0.13.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this without 0.13 pandas? I am having so much difficulty to install 0.13... thanks

Comment: @CharlesM not as easily. What seems to be the issue installing? Are you using pip or anaconda?

Comment: With pip `pip install pandas==0.13` It won't update. I have this error `InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\chamar.stu\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_chamar.stu\\pandas\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\chamar.stu\appdata\local\temp\pip-lnk0ul-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\chamar.stu\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_chamar.stu\pandas`

Comment: How did you install the earlier version of pandas? Might be worth asking this as a separate question. I recommend anaconda.